# Is React Router causing my component to render twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

### Background

I have a list of items. If you click on a detail link under an item, you are taken to its page where it allows you to read and add comments about that particular item. Currently, the comments component is rendering both on the [index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqYOb.jpg) and on the [item details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN7NZ.jpg). It should only render on the latter.

Can you help me figure out why?

### Troubleshooting

I checked my routes and my Comments and Comment components but did not see any obvious errors. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269961/react-router-component-rendering-twice) about rendering components twice, but my situation is different because I have to use `render=` to pass down props.

I'll admit, I have never tried to build a route like this, so maybe I am not approaching it properly. The one is question is the 2nd from the bottom in this list below.

***Routes***

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={(routerProps) => <Programs {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs}/>} /> />
          <Route exact path='/programs' render={(routerProps) => <Programs {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs} />} />
          <Route path='/programs/new' render={(routerProps) => <ProgramInput {...routerProps}/>}/>
          <Route path='/programs/:id' render={(routerProps) => <Program {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs}/>}/>
          <Route exact path='/programs/:id/comments' render={(routerProps) => <Program {...routerProps} program={this.props.program}/>}/>
          <Route exact path='/watchlist' render={(routerProps) => <Program {...routerProps} programs={this.props.programs} />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**CommentsContainer**

```
class CommentsContainer extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Comments comments={this.props.program && this.props.program.comments}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CommentsContainer
```

**Program (where CommentsContainer is rendered)**

```
I took out some of the Card code for brevity. There is More link inside the card that takes you to the item page. That part works fine.

return(
        <Fragment>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Card as='div'>
             </Card>
          </Grid.Column>

          <CommentsContainer program={program}/>

        </Fragment>
      )
    }
```

**Comments**

```
const Comments = (props) => {
  // console.log(props.comments && props.comments.map(comment => console.log(comment))
  return(
    <Comment.Group>


      {props.comments && props.comments.map(comment => <CommentCard key={comment.id} comment={comment}/>)}


    </Comment.Group>
  )
}

export default Comments
```

***ComentCard***
I don't think the issue lies here, but [here's a link](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/comments/CommentCard.js) if you need to see the file.

### Backend

I am using Rails API for my backend. [Here is a link to my `comments_controller` if you want to take a peek.](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-backend/blob/master/app/controllers/api/v1/comments_controller.rb)

#### Thank you for your time and advice!

Comment: I don't see your routes in the repo??

Comment: @MattOestreich Different routes than the first code block I listed above?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the js file containing the routes above.

Comment: @MattOestreich A ha! That's right [here](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/containers/ProgramsContainer.js).

Comment: ...and which routes does that happen on? I have no idea which pages are your index page and item details page. Tell me the exact routes this happens on, please.

Comment: I assume this is happening on routes which you are rendering `<Program../>` - it looks like inside of that Program component, you are rendering the Comments component, which would make this expected behavior.  If you uncomment [this line](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/757f3728dc518140ccb3934fc2cf7b42f10e25f1/src/components/programs/Program.js#L80) does the issue go away?

Comment: Apologies. I uploaded some pictures but it seems like it would help you if I added more detail regarding the routes. The issue happens on `/programs`(2nd from top) and `/programs/:id/comments` (2nd from bottom).

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like that removes Comments in `/programs/` and on the `/programs/:id/comments` page. That's where I am passing my props down from Program > Comments > Comment.

Comment: Ok so this is only happening on routes that are using `<Programs/>` - inside of Programs, you are calling Program, inside of Program you are calling Comments - that is most likely why this is happening... [Here is where you](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/757f3728dc518140ccb3934fc2cf7b42f10e25f1/src/components/programs/Programs.js#L22) are calling Program inside of Programs, which in turn is calling Comments.

Comment: So when you comment that line, the issue does or does not go away?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198784/discussion-between-koberlander-and-matt-oestreich).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did end up being a routes issue. Both my `/programs` and my `/` routes were displaying my CommentsContainer because I needed to add a ternary to essentially filter those routes out.

I added this code in my Programs (plural) component right after my Card component. It uses `props.match` to check if the route being rendered was NOT `/programs` and NOT `/`. When that statement evaluated to true, the CommentsContainer and associated comments were rendered on the `/programs/:id`. If either of those statements evaluated to true, it didn't render anything.

```
{this.props.match.url !== '/programs' && this.props.match.url !== '/'? <CommentsContainer program={program}/> : null}
```

Since I only passed down routerProps in my *Programs.js* file, I had to pass down `props.match` from Programs to my Program component (which renders the cards and CommentContainer). Doing this allows the ternary above to work.

```
{props.programs && props.programs.map((program) => <Program key={program.name} program={program} match={props.match}/>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the `CommentsContainer` to show when there are comments, you can just replace the line where it's rendered with:

```
{program.comments && <CommentsContainer program={program}/>}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Matt Oestreich pointed out earlier you always render comments when you render the Program component. The Programs (plural) component is basically a list that consists of Program components. So when you render the Programs component you always render the CommentsContainer with the Comment Component.

So maybe you can make another component, the ProgramDetails Component where you include the CommentsContainer. In the Program Component you can link to the ProgramDetails Component. I think this would prevent that the comments render in the Programs (plural) is rendered.